# Service-specific releases vs Releasing all services on every change

Tags: continuous-integration, release-management, services, orchestration

The following applies to a platform/company at an **early stage** in its life, moving quickly and cheaply with a small engineering team.

Imagine a platform with the following components:

- Cloud infrastructure (e.g. terraform)
- Client-facing app
- Internal-facing admin app
- Third-party API
- Shared relational DB, with frequent schema changes

For many of the past years, if I were to build this from scratch, I'd have isolated these components (let's just call them all services for simplicity) as much as possible from the beginning, in their own repos, with their own build pipelines, given they have different use cases despite interdependencies (DB and infra in particular). They'd also have their own releases. If a change is just being made to the internal admin tool, there would be no reason to trigger a release of the client-facing app at the same time. This clearly reduces some risk (and, a more minor benefit of quicker, leaner releases).

However, again and again in my teams I've seen how much complexity, overhead and frankly risk, gets added with coordinating individual service releases. A new product feature that requires a schema change, as well as one or more changes in other services, needs a lot of brainpower to release correctly. Starting from the PRs, reviewers can only see part of the overall change, which adds risk from them not seeing the big picture. Then there is releasing these independent updates to an environment, ensuring the build is done in the right order and that the correct branches are all being used. This gets even crazier when you've got automation or end-to-end testing that depends on seeded data, or more granular and versioned shared packages.

Is all this headache really worth it at an early stage? Is it so wrong to through everything in a monorepo, and any little change anywhere rebuilds the entire platform, right down to the infra (granted, if using terraform at least, would do a diff and only apply if changed)? If the build pipeline is robust and well-integrated with one of the main cloud providers, re-releasing a service that didn't actually change shouldn't cause any issues. And you get the benefit of seeing an entire cross-platform change at once without dealing with multiple dependent releases, with a single build that is hardwired to release in the correct order, with holistic cross-platform smoke testing. Yes, builds will be slower, possibly with a lot of unnecessary steps, but let's assume there's also a pretty good local environment setup so that deploys to a cloud test environment aren't too frequent.

Thoughts? As a reminder, please view your opinions through the lens of a small, scrappy team. If you have a big org with delivery managers and all kinds of orchestration tooling, then maybe the problem isn't as severe.

Answer (score 0):

I've lived through something similar and I've lived through the consequences of someone else doing this so I can say with some confidence that it's a mixed bag.  There isn't a clear winner, it really depends on what you need.

### Single Repo vs Multiple Repos

This is mostly organizational for me.  I've been in places that have done it both ways.  A single repo can work well when the codebase is small.  It makes it easy to share common code between apps / projects.  And, as you pointed out, it makes it easier to see the scope of a set of changes when they are all gathered together.

But a single repo also has it's downsides.  Like I said before, being able to easily share code between apps / projects can be a good thing, especially when you want to move fast and don't want to rewrite code / setup package repositories or something similar.  But that can also be a curse.  Because it makes it easy to share, you are more likely to share in ways that tightly couple your code or apps together.  IE. making a change to the client app might affect the internal admin app.  And that might be ok (so you can catch things early) or it might not (it might turn a simple change into something much more complex).  That added coupling means that any change you make really affects the whole codebase, not just a single app.  And that usually means you need to keep the whole codebase in your head when you are working or planning, which isn't easy.  Especially as you grow.  Where I work now has a mono-repo where some projects are referenced in 40+ different deployable applications.  Making changes to those projects is hard and scary and we are paying for that decision someone made a long time ago.

Personally, I prefer to keep separate repos for different deployable applications because it forces me to be more disciplined in what I do.  But that comes with a cost of slower short-term development velocity in favor of more consistent long-term velocity.

### Deploy Everything vs Targeted Deployments

This one depends a lot on what your business requirements on uptime are. If you can have frequent enough and long enough maintenance / downtime windows, having a larger-than-necessary release may not matter.  If that isn't the case, then you need to do something more targeted so you can get your changes out without breaking SLAs.  Where I worked where we deployed everything, we only had 2 apps and it took all of 15 minutes to deploy.  We also only really needed to be up during daytime hours, so no one cared if the site was down for a few minutes in the middle of the night.  Where I work now (where we need to be up pretty much 24/7 and have grown to 70+ apps), we couldn't get away with that at all.

### Overall

A lot of this falls into the discussion of pay now vs pay later.  If this is never going to grow beyond a small codebase and a couple of apps, you can probably get away with a mono-repo and deploying everything and call it a day.  If you think it'll grow beyond where that is feasible, you have to decide whether increased velocity and ease of coding now are worth having to rework all this in the future when things are established and entrenched and harder to change.  Sometimes getting to market faster now means you'll have a job later where you can go back and fix things (and failing to do so soon means your company goes under).  Sometimes things aren't so urgent and it's worth spending the time now to make your life easier overall.